# have the best random possible

Tags: c#, random

I'm having trouble with the random object in C#.

I've a static variable "Random" like this :

```
private static Random _myRandomObjet = new Random();
```

After i've a self made timer (while loop + stopwatch to ensure precision) which calls this methods each 10ms :

```
private void MyMethod()
{
      if(_myRandomObjet.Next(0,10) == 9)
      { // 1 chance / 9
         //SOME CODE

         if(_myRandomObjet.Next(0,10) == 9)
         {

         }

         // SOME CODE
      } 

}
```

The aim of this code is to enter the if in 10% of the cases but it seems most of the times the two random.next are giving me the same value.

How can I improve that ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your test code as well so we can run it and check exactly what's going on. Also where is that `_myRandomObjet` being stored? Is it at the program level or is it being stored on instances of objects that you are creating multiple copies of?

Comment: Are you certain they give you the same value?  Or are you just _perceiving_ that since you have another check to see if the _next_  random value is `9` also?

Comment: @Chris : `_myRandomObjet` is a static member, so unless it is re-assigned elsewhere, only one instance is used

Comment: you made a timer by self ? why the System.Timers.Timer is as precise as the Stopwatch and does not blur 100% cpu time

Comment: @Gabi: so it is. My bad. :)

Comment: The code as presented should be about as random as you get. If there are problems with its randomness then they are in code that you have not shown here.

Comment: probably meaningless but your 2nd `// some code` is not in the 2nd `if` scope.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this problem is given [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx)

The solution provided in this article is

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public static class RandomProvider
{    
    private static int seed = Environment.TickCount;

    private static ThreadLocal<Random> randomWrapper = new ThreadLocal<Random>(() =>
        new Random(Interlocked.Increment(ref seed))
    );

    public static Random GetThreadRandom()
    {
        return randomWrapper.Value;
    }
}
```

Read the article in depth for more details.

You can also try using

```
Random rand = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
```

Comment: This is indeed a "better" way to get random numbers in general, but does not address the problem above.